# i am getting error when try to run my Node App

Tags: node.js

I am trying to run my node app from server, i installed nodejs and in my terminal wrote: node server.js   (server.js is my app)
then immediately appear error, i was searching in internet but i can't find any help, i have almost 1 week searching for help :(

```
Error: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /home/usr1/public_html/trackers/astorNode/node_modules/scrypt/build/Release/scrypt.node)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:718:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/usr1/public_html/trackers/astorNode/node_modules/scrypt/index.js:3:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
```

thanks for your help !

Comment: It's hard to help you without knowing more about your environment. Linux? Debian / Ubuntu? Still, it looks like a problem installing nodejs and its dependencies: scrypt doesn't have the right version of a runtime library it needs. Reinstall nodejs following the installation instructions very carefully.

Comment: my OS is Linux Centos 7, i test whit nodejs version 16.0 and version 10.15.1 but always it showsthe same error, i am doing it in a cloud server service not in my local network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing libgcc and also check the LD_LIBRARY_PATH